# how to get a certain output out of a button

Tags: python, parsing, tkinter

I made a button. I want to try and initiate a certain function user inputs 'x' and presses the button. This is the code I have so far but i am not sure  how to go about it

```
self.submit = Button(text='Submit', font_size= 35)
    self.submit.bind(on_press = self.pressed)   
    self.add_widget(self.submit)   

def pressed(self, instance):
    for x in soup.select('.genre'):
        print(x.text)
```

Comment: Hello, you may want to read up on asking a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also you should have minimal amount of code possible which will run for us. You have that code as part of a class but the rest of the class is missing. Also, it looks like you are doing a global import * you should do `import tkinter as tk` to avoid namespace clutter.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Use the `command` option for the button:

```py
    self.submit = Button(self, text='Submit', font_size=35, command=self.pressed)
    self.submit.grid()

def pressed(self, event):
    # Do stuff here.
```

That way, every time the button is clicked, it runs the designated function.

For more info, click [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm).